# JSF 2.0 "Conversion Error setting value 'courseID' for 'null Converter'.!!How can I avoid this kinda error?

Tags: java, jsf, converters

I am working on a web application using PrimeFaces, JPA, Hibernate and JSF 2.0.

I have two entities `Students` and `Course` with an many to one relationship.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
public class Students extends MainUsers implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private long mobile;
    private String jobTitle;
    private int duration;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startDate;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date endDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", nullable = true)
    private Course company;

    // Getters and setters.
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "course.findCourseByCourseId", query = "select c from Course c where c.Id =:id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "course.findCourseByCourseName", query = "select c from Course c where c.courseName =:courseName") })
public class Course implements Serializable {

    public static final String FIND_COURSE_BY_COURSE_ID = "course.findByCourseId";
    public static final String FIND_COURSE_COURSE_NAME = "course.findByCourseName";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int Id;
    private String courseName;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Students.class, mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Students> students;

    // Getters and setters.

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Course) {
            Course course = (Course) obj;
            return course.getId() == Id;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

I have a registration page where it takes student's names, email, password and course. For selecting the course I have used this

```html
<h:outputText value="Course :" />
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{courseMB.course}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one Course" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{courseMB.allCourses}" var="crs"
        itemLabel="#{crs.courseName}" itemValue="#{crs.id}" />
    <f:converter converterId = "courseConverter"/>  
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

To create a student I have the following method in StudentMB class:

```java
public void createStudent() {       
    String test = student.getEmail();

    if (getStudentFacade().isStudentExist(test)){
        System.out.println(test);
    } else {
        try {
            student.setActivation_key(hashKey());
            student.setRole(Role.STUDENT);
            student.setActive(0);
            getStudentFacade().createStudent(student);
            displayInfoMessageToUser("Created with success");
            SendEmail.Send(username, password, student.getEmail(), title, linkToSend());
            loadStudent();
            resetStudent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            displayErrorMessageToUser("Opps, we could not create the user. Try again");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really know how to get the course into StudentMB and persist that into the database. The current methodology gives me an error

> Conversion Error setting value 'courseID' for 'null Converter'.

I tried to use a converter but I am getting empty string into the argument.

```java
@FacesConverter(value="courseConverter", forClass = com.model.Course.class)
public class CourseConverter implements Converter  {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        CourseFacade courseFacade = new CourseFacade();
        int courseId;

        try {
            courseId = Integer.parseInt(submittedValue);
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                "Type the name of a Course and select it (or use the dropdown)", 
                "Type the name of a Course and select it (or use the dropdown)"));
        }

        return courseFacade.findCourse(courseId);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        Course course = null;
        if (modelValue instanceof Course){
            course = (Course) modelValue;
            StringBuilder asString = new StringBuilder();
            asString.append(course.getId()+"-");
            asString.append(course.getCourseName());
            return asString.toString();

        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the return type of `getAllCourses()` method? It should be a list of `SelectItem`s.

Comment: return is list of course.It returns a list of course with ID, CourseName

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the select item value to the `Course` itself, not to its `id`.

Replace

```
itemValue="#{crs.id}"
```

by

```
itemValue="#{crs}"
```

Otherwise the converter would only get the `#{crs.id}` as `modelValue` in `getAsString()` and thus return an empty string. This empty string is in turn submitted back to the server through `getAsObject()` which in turn causes the exception.

You should have thrown a `ConverterException` in the `else` part of the `if (modelValue instanceof Course)` so that it was immediately clear that the converter isn't suitable for the given model value.

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: Thank you very much . But I am getting new error """Conversion Error setting value 'BE Process & Chemical Engineering' for 'null Converter'."""" I get this error when I select the course from the selects.

Comment: If you get the `null converter` error, then it basically means that no converter can be found for the `Course` class. Have you changed the `<f:converter>` or `@FacesConverter` after you posted the initial question?

Comment: No, I did not change anything. All i did is just change #{crs.id } to #{crs} as you said. I have @ManagedConverter(name="courseConverterBean"), tried , but did not work.

Comment: *@ManagedBean(name="courseConverterBean")